# Radio buttons not checked in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this line of code for page load:

```
if ($("input").is(':checked')) {
```

and it works fine when the radio button input is checked.  However, I want the opposite.  Something along the lines of

```
if ($("input").not(.is(':checked'))) {
```

so that my if statement runs when none of the radiobuttons are selected.  What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
if ( ! $("input").is(':checked') )
```

Doesn't work?

You might also try iterating over the elements like so:

```
var iz_checked = true;
$('input').each(function(){
   iz_checked = iz_checked && $(this).is(':checked');
});
if ( ! iz_checked )
```

Comment: You might also filter that list by the name attribute this group of radio buttons share.

Comment: `if ( !($("input").is(':checked')) )`  I'll add extra parenthesis too to make it better.

Answer (score 26):

```
if ($("input").is(":not(:checked)"))
```

AFAIK, this should work, tested against the latest stable jQuery (1.2.6).

Answer (score 10):

If my firebug profiler work fine (and i know how to use it well), this:

```
$('#communitymode').attr('checked')
```

is faster than

```
$('#communitymode').is('checked')
```

You can try on this page :)

And then you can use it like

```
if($('#communitymode').attr('checked')===true) { 
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$("input").is(":not(':checked')"))
```

This is jquery 1.3, mind the ' and " signs!

Answer (score 7):

```
$('input:radio[checked=false]');
```

this will also work

```
input:radio:not(:checked)
```

or

```
:radio:not(:checked)
```

Comment: This will work for sure. Took me a while to figure out. It's the most elegant you can get without writing any code.

Comment: Works great for me as selector as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
(!$('#radio').is(':checked'))
```

This worked for me

Answer (score -1):

This works too. It seems shortest working notation:
`!$('#selector:checked')`