# Radio button validator

Tags: php, javascript, validation, radio-button

How can I validate radio buttons? Because this won't work at all. The radio button `name` and `ID` is `billable` and their `value` is either `yes` or `no`.

```
function formValidator() {  
  var errors = new Array();   

  if($("#billable").checked == false) {  
    errors[0] = "*Billable - Required";  
  }

  if(errors.length > 0) {  
    var error_msg = 'Please review:';  

    for(i=0;i<errors.length;i++) {  
      if(errors[i]!=undefined) {  
        error_msg = error_msg + "\n" + errors[i];  
      }  
    }  

    alert(error_msg);  

    return false;  
  }

  return true;  
}
```

Comment: It's a radio or a check button?

Comment: `$("#billable")` suggests a JavaScript library; you should mention which one so you can leverage it. Also, you haven't accepted a single answer since you joined Stack Overflow. That can discourage some potential answers.

Comment: and you listed 'php' as a tag when this isn't about php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
$("#billable:checked").size()
```

---

Using `$("#billable").checked` you will get `undefined`, because this property doesn't exist.
With `$("#billable:checked").size()` you will get how many checked radios do you have (0 or 1)

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/STSkt/).

Comment: He's asking for JavaScript, not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

if you try sometime with the [JQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), all you will need is something like:

```
rules: {
'billable[]':{ required:true }
}
```

### Edited:

as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372325/radio-buttons-not-checked-in-jquery), this will help you:

```
var iz_checked = true;
$('input').each(function(){
   iz_checked = iz_checked && $(this).is(':checked');
});
if ( ! iz_checked )
```

Comment: Okay, but even though I've chosen a radio button already, it will still alert.

Comment: Here's part of the form:
 <td><?php  if ($billable == "yes") {?>
 <input type="radio" name="billable" id="billable" value="yes" checked /> Yes
<input type="radio" name="billable" id="billable" value="no"/> No
<?php } else if ($billable == "no"){?>
<input type="radio" name="billable" id="billable" value="yes"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="billable" id="billable" value="no" checked /> No
<?php }else{ ?>
<input type="radio" name="billable" id="billable" value="yes"/> Yes
<input type="radio" name="billable" id="billable" value="no"/> No
                  <?php } ?>
                  </td>

Comment: Sorry for not placing spaces but it's just short so i think it's understandable. thanks!