# Prevent swiching type="radio" elements after restoring Firefox tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two < input > elements type="radio". One of them is checked by default. In Firefox browser when I check another < input > element which is not a default one, and when I close the tab and restore that tab back I've got that "not a default" < input > element is CHECKED! (In Chrome it's not happening.) That's not ok 'cause the price is from another option and a picture belongs to another option.

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('input').prop('checked', true); 
    };
```

I was trying to add this to "reload" check element, but this "script" forces element to be checked after page is loaded if it was being changed WHILE the page is loading...

This is the page code:

```
            <div class="radio">

            <input class="not4kt" autocomplete="off" name="option[23]"
    value="52" id="option-value-52" data-price_prefix="-"
    data-price="205.0000" onchange="recalculateprice('117_cp');"
 onclick="chimg('117', '33')" type="radio">

            <label for="option-value-52"></label>
            <label for="option-value-52">
            <span>33 см</span>                                  
            </label>

            </div>

        <div class="radio">

            <input class="rst4kt" autocomplete="off" checked="checked" name="option[23]" value="51"
    id="option-value-51" data-price_prefix="+" data-price="0.0000"
    onchange="recalculateprice('117_cp');"
onclick="chimg('117', '44')" type="radio">


            <label for="option-value-51"></label>
            <label for="option-value-51">
            <span>44 см</span></label>

            </div>
```

**How can I get both?** --> (1) keep the element checked by default to be checked after restoring the Firefox tab; (2) prevent switching to the "checked by default" element after the page is loaded if WHILE the page was loading another element was clicked.

**UPD!**
Actually I have ~20 dynamically changing IDs inside of < input > ... So I can't use #optionval-a ... cause it always might be #optionval-b or #optionval-foo-bar or even #optionval-123... The only possible way to call the elemnt is: $('input') -- and that's the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now sure what you mean by the first requirement - do you mean reloading the page? If so, you should expect the browser to load the page with the default element checked.

To prevent the checkbox being set to the default if a user has checked a button before the page has finished loading - i.e. before the `$(window).load(...)` function is called, you could set that function to check on the status of the radio element, though I think you will need to rewrite the function, as at the moment it will run through ticking each box until it finds the last 'input' element, because the jQuery selector in the above code is set to `input`, although you probably meant `:input`, but anyway, to allow a user to select a box before the page is loaded without the onload function re-setting the choice, you could check that every other box was not checked  to be sure it was OK to check the default box:

```
$(window).load(function(){
     if (!$('#optionval-a').is(':checked' && !$('#option-value-b').is(':checked' && !$('#option-value-c').is(':checked'){
          $("#option-value-51").prop("checked", true);
     } 
}
```

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372325/radio-buttons-not-checked-in-jquery) might be helpful.

If you mean that Firefox seems to be caching a user's input if they immediately re-load the page after closing using Ctrl + Shift + t, then I think they would be doing that deliberately to help users they believe wish to open the last tab exactly as they had left it. The only solution I can think of for this case would be a script using setTimeout() or equivalent jQuery function which you could perhaps set on page load, since I doubt Firefox would over-ride any such behaviour on page load. Thus:

```
$(window).load(function(){
       // possibly set radio boxes here...
       // ...or better still do everything inside the timeout function, thereby solving both problems at once:
       setTimeout(function(){ alert("I really want my page to do this"); }, 3000); 
}
```

One alternative might be not to fully show the form until the page has finished loading. Or you could insert a hidden input radio element (whose name is static - like name="hiddenCheckedRadioElement" ) first in the list with "checked" and then check if it is still checked once the page is loaded. If so, check your chosen field. If it is not checked it would mean the user has selected something else, and so you would then not check your default box.

Comment: No, not reloading the page... If I just reload the page everything is ok. Firefox swiches a < input > element just right after the page is completly loaded TO the last CLICKED element... This happens ONLY if I close the tab and restore that tab by CTRL + SHIFT + T.

Comment: It could help... but... Actually I have ~20 dynamically changing IDs... So I can't use #optionval-a ... cause it always might be #optionval-b or #optionval-foo-bar or even #optionval-123... The only possible way to call the elemnt is: $('input') -- and that's the problem...

Comment: An alternative might be not to fully show the form until the page has finished loading. Or you could insert a hidden input radio element (whose name is static - like name="hiddenCheckedRadioElement" ) first in the list with "checked" and then check if it is still checked once the page is loaded. If so, check your chosen field. If it is not checked it would mean the user has selected something else, and so you would then not check your default box.

Comment: Wow! That's an awesome idea! I'll try... Thank you a lot!